# Adding UISearchBar into UITableView which is subview of UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, ios-autolayout

I am facing an issue while adding `UISearchBar`as a subview for `UITableView` header. Basically a View(HeaderView) contains button and search bar which is added to table view as header view.table view itself is added as subview in `UIViewController`.

Above implementation uses auto layout approach however, when code runs search bar is not appearing.

Could you please suggest some `direction/example/blog.` \

Appreciate your effort and thanks in advance!!!

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: can you please post your XIB/Storyboard screenshot and also the constraints

Comment: thanks Vinay for looking into it. I have applied screenshot.